# Sql query to get total payments by customer type (1,2,3,4,5) in each month of given year

Tags: sql-server

I have 2 tables Payments and Customers.

We have 5 types of customer 1,2,3,4,5.

I want to get total payments by customer type (1,2,3,4,5) in each month of given year.

And if any customer type not have any payment than it should be 0.

Below is my current query :-

```
 SELECT 
                    "Month" = month(o.PaymentDate)
                     , "Year" = year(o.PaymentDate)
                     , Amount = sum(o.Amount)
                     , c.CustomerTypeID                  
                FROM
                    Payments o
                    INNER JOIN
                      Customers c ON o.CustomerID = c.CustomerID
                WHERE
                    o.PaymentDate >= convert(DATETIME, '1/1/2013 12:00:00 AM')
                    AND o.PaymentDate < convert(DATETIME, '12/31/2013 12:00:00 AM')
                GROUP BY
                    month(o.PaymentDate)
                  , year(o.PaymentDate)
                  ,c.CustomerTypeID     
                ORDER BY
                    year(o.PaymentDate)
                  , month(o.PaymentDate)
                      ,c.CustomerTypeID
```

And Result is :-

Month     Year      Amout    CustomerTypeID
1            2013       456        1
1            2013       678        2
1            2013       346        3
1            2013       3245       5

As currently it is not giving data for CustomerType 4, so I want to show 0 in amount column and month and Year will be same.

Can any body help me.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT 
    2013 as year,
    months.monthno,
    Amount = isnull(sum(o.Amount),0),
    c.CustomerTypeID  
FROM
    customers c 
         cross join     
    (select number monthNo from master..spt_values where type='p' and number between 1 and 12) months
         left join payments o
     ON o.CustomerID = c.CustomerID
     AND year(o.PaymentDate)=2013
     AND month(o.PaymentDate) = months.monthNo
GROUP BY
    months.monthno, c.CustomerTypeID
ORDER BY
    months.monthno, c.CustomerTypeID
```

Comment: Thank you very much @Podiluska, It is working fine now. You are the champ :-).

Answer (score 0):

Use Right outer join to have all customers and Coalesce(amount,0) for returning 0 instead of null.

```
SELECT 
                      c.CustomerTypeID                  
                FROM
                    (SELECT "Month" = month(o.PaymentDate)
                             , "Year" = year(o.PaymentDate)
                             , Amount = sum(o.Amount) 
                             , o.CustomerID
                    FROM Payments o
                    WHERE
                    o.PaymentDate >= convert(DATETIME, '1/1/2013 12:00:00 AM')
                    AND o.PaymentDate < convert(DATETIME, '12/31/2013 12:00:00 AM')
                    ) D
                    RIGHT OUTER JOIN
                      Customers c ON o.CustomerID = c.CustomerID
                GROUP BY
                    D.MONTH
                  , D.YEAR
                  ,c.CustomerTypeID     
                 ORDER BY
                       D.MONTH
                      , D.YEAR
                      ,c.CustomerTypeID
```

Comment: Thanks @Amirreza, I replaced inner join with right outer join, but same result. Can you post sql query here?

Comment: And also it is not returning NULL for customer type 4. It is not coming with result. Because there is no data(amount) for customertype 4. But I want to get it as a default 0.

Comment: I Edited my post ,but i Wrote this from your query and might be a little problem on it. so if it not worked ,get the idea and make it true .

Answer (score 0):

When you use `WHERE` with aggregation you should seriously consider using `GROUP BY ALL` and not `GROUP BY`:

From -  [MS Technet](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175028(v=sql.90).aspx):

If you use ALL, the query results include all groups produced by the GROUP BY clause, even if some of the groups have no rows that meet the search conditions. Without ALL, a SELECT statement that includes GROUP BY does not show groups for which no rows qualify.

```
SELECT 
                    "Month" = month(o.PaymentDate)
                     , "Year" = year(o.PaymentDate)
                     , Amount = sum(o.Amount)
                     , c.CustomerTypeID                  
                FROM
                    Payments o
                    INNER JOIN
                      Customers c ON o.CustomerID = c.CustomerID
                WHERE
                    o.PaymentDate >= convert(DATETIME, '1/1/2013 12:00:00 AM')
                    AND o.PaymentDate < convert(DATETIME, '12/31/2013 12:00:00 AM')
                GROUP BY ALL
                    month(o.PaymentDate)
                  , year(o.PaymentDate)
                  ,c.CustomerTypeID     
                ORDER BY
                    year(o.PaymentDate)
                  , month(o.PaymentDate)
                      ,c.CustomerTypeID
```

Comment: Thanks @Yosi, But it is not giving desire result.

Comment: @AnandMeena - Any way it will be a bug if you don't use it, you need all customers data...

Comment: You should **not** use `group by all`. From that TechNet article : "GROUP BY ALL will be removed in a future version of Microsoft SQL Server. Avoid using GROUP BY ALL in new development work, and plan to modify applications that currently use it"

Comment: Thanks @Yosi, But there is still something wrong, because it is returning 227 rows. These should be total 60 rows (12 months * 5 Type) for each year.